# How to search for a specific keyword from a string and return its index number

Tags: python-3.x, string

Q- A researcher has gathered thousands of news articles. But she wants to focus her attention on articles including a specific word. Complete the function below to help her filter her list of articles.

Your function should meet the following criteria

- Do not include documents where the keyword string shows up only as a part of a larger word. For example, if she were looking for the keyword “closed”, you would not include the string “enclosed.”
- She does not want you to distinguish upper case from lower case letters. So the phrase “Closed the case.” would be included when the keyword is “closed”
- Do not let periods or commas affect what is matched. “It is closed.” would be included when the keyword is “closed”. But you can assume there are no other types of punctuation.

I have tried to slice the string and store it in a list and get the index number

```
    def word_search(documents, keyword):
        l=[]
        for i, doc in enumerate(documents):
            spliting = doc.split()
            for split in spliting:
                normalized = split.rstrip('.,').lower()
            if keyword.lower() in normalized:
                l.append(i)
        return i

word_search('Hey welcome to the python programming language','python')
```

I expect the output of  "python" index at [4] but getting the length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: list should be passed as first argument

```
>>> def word_search(docs, keyw):
        for i, doc in enumerate(docs):
            words = doc.lower().split()
            if keyw in words:
               print(doc, words.index(keyw))


>>> word_search(['The Learn Python Challenge Casino', 'They bought a car, and a horse', 'Casinoville?'], 'casino')
The Learn Python Challenge Casino 4
```

Comment: word_search [['The Learn Python Challenge Casino', 'They bought a car, and a horse', 'Casinoville?'], 'casino']

what if  you will give this as a argument

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns the last `i`, meaning the last index of the for-loop. You probably need to return the variable that holds the results.

You can try something like this:

```
def word_search_2(title_list, keyword):
    # make lowercase and remove punctuation
    keyword = keyword.lower().strip('.,')

    result_list = []
    for i, title in enumerate(title_list):
        # make lowercase and remove punctuation, then split into words
        words = title.lower().strip('.,').split()

        if keyword in words:
            result_list.append((i, title))

    return result_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    docs = [
        'The Learn Python Challenge Casino',
        'They bought a car, and a horse',
        'The big casino.',
        'Casinoville?',
    ]
    w = 'casino'

    print(word_search_2(docs, w))
```

The output is:

```
[(0, 'The Learn Python Challenge Casino'), (2, 'The big casino.')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
index=[]
for i,doc in enumerate(doc_list):
    words = doc.replace(".","").replace(",","").split(" ")
    keyword_found=len([word for word in words if word.lower()==keyword.lower()])
  
    if keyword_found>=1:
        index.append(i)
return index
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you needs to use this code [Reference](https://www.kaggle.com/stegua/learn-python-challenge-day-6?scriptVersionId=4167921&cellId=14)

```
def word_search(doc_list, keyword):
        """
        Takes a list of documents (each document is a string) and a keyword. 
        Returns list of the index values into the original list for all documents 
        containing the keyword.
    
        Example:
        doc_list = ["The Learn Python Challenge Casino.", "They bought a car", "Casinoville"]
        >>> word_search(doc_list, 'casino')
        >>> [0]
        """
        Ls = []
        for i, doc in enumerate(doc_list):
            for word in doc.replace(',','').replace('.','').split(' '):            
                if keyword.lower() == word.lower():
                    Ls.append(i)
                    break
        return Ls
    
    
    q2.check()
```